# Add Value in excel cell after 7 cell space in column wise

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to add number after 7 cell space with continue like as 1.......2......3 in column wise not row wise every number having space of 7 cells please help me

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and the problems you had with it in your question.

Comment: i dont know vba programming language if you know how it is done then provide me a script or if you know manual way then tell me

Comment: i dont know VBA if you have solution of this problem then provide me

Comment: You dont need VBA for this.

Comment: any manual way for this solution like as cell format or cell rule

Answer (score 1):

One approach to do doing this:

Place this is the first column:

`=IF(MOD(COLUMN()-1,8)=0,(COLUMN()-1)/8+1,"")`

Then drag across from the bottom right corner. This will calculate consecutive numbers in every eighth column containing this formula.

[image]

Comment: THANKS DEAR BUT ONE PROBLEM

Comment: 7653662,
9711711,
9712299,
9710838,
7654623,
5815451,
7654707,
5816685
if i want these number after space then what to do

Comment: @MuhammadYasir Where are you retrieving these values from? Is it in a consecutive range of cells?

Comment: THESE values are manual values i want to format sheet cells as i paste values in sheet column wise then every value paste in cells with 7 cell space